# python apscheduler not execute by cron for every 1 minute

Tags: python

I am using apscheduler to make a cron job, now I want to make the work execute every 1 minute. This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        scheduler.shutdown()


@scheduler.scheduled_job(IntervalTrigger(seconds=60))
def func_to_be_executed():
    print("I am running......")
```

But the job only execute once, what should I to to make it execute every minute using cron way?

Comment: The `/1` does not make much sense.

Comment: I ignore some important parameter?@KlausD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the decorator approach. It should work.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()

@scheduler.scheduled_job(IntervalTrigger(seconds=60))
def func_to_be_executed():
  pass
```

Code for BlockingSchedular - use when the scheduler is the only thing running in your process

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job(IntervalTrigger(seconds=10))
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every 10 seconds.')

sched.start()
```

Comment: How to keep it running? the app exit after execute @Simplecode

Comment: @scheduler.scheduled_job(IntervalTrigger(seconds=60))
AttributeError: type object 'scheduler' has no attribute 'scheduled_job'

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'scheduler' has no attribute 'scheduled_job' - I don't get this error, using APScheduler version 3.6.3

How to keep it running -   Do you use  flask or any other server ?

Comment: @Dolphin, in that case pls. use BlockingScheduler() instead of BackgroundScheduler(). Pls. see the answer is updated with new code as well. Run the BlockingSchedular script - python <script_path> and let me know.